# Tkinter, передать значение из Radiobutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне передать значение из Radiobutton, всё работает если это только одна функция, но как только делаю функцию в функции, она отказывается передавать значение. 
Ниже просто скрипт как пример
Заранее спасибо!

```
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter.ttk import Radiobutton  

def ccc(): 
    ccc = Tk()
    ccc.title("ccc")
    ccc.geometry("400x250")
    def clicked():  
        print(selected.get())

    selected = IntVar()  
    rad1 = Radiobutton(ccc,text='Первый', value=1, variable=selected)  
    rad2 = Radiobutton(ccc,text='Второй', value=2, variable=selected)  
    rad3 = Radiobutton(ccc,text='Третий', value=3, variable=selected)  
    btn = Button(ccc, text="Клик", command=clicked)  
    lbl = Label(ccc)  
    rad1.grid(column=0, row=0)  
    rad2.grid(column=1, row=0)  
    rad3.grid(column=2, row=0)  
    btn.grid(column=3, row=0)  
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)  
    ccc.mainloop()
window = Tk()  
window.title("ТТТ")  
window.geometry('400x250') 
btt = Button(window, text="клик", command=ccc)
btt.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: что должно куда передавать?

Comment: в функции def ccc() должен выводить выбранный элемент 1, 2 или 3

Comment: Вкратце: дочерние окна нужно создавать как объект Toplevel, а не Tk, иначе будут проблемы с получением значений из переменных (из IntVar, например)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Radiobutton


class ChildWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Дочернее окно")
        self.geometry("400x250")

        self.selected = IntVar()

        radio_button = Radiobutton(self,text='Первый', value=1, variable=self.selected)
        radio_button_1 = Radiobutton(self,text='Второй', value=2, variable=self.selected)
        radio_button_2 = Radiobutton(self,text='Третий', value=3, variable=self.selected)

        radio_button.configure(command=self.information)
        radio_button_1.configure(command=self.information)
        radio_button_2.configure(command=self.information)

        radio_button.grid(column=0, row=0)
        radio_button_1.grid(column=1, row=0)
        radio_button_2.grid(column=2, row=0)

        self.info = Label(self, text='Не выбрана')
        self.info['text'] = self.selected.get()
        self.info.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def information(self):
        self.info['text'] = self.selected.get()

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Главное окно")
        self.geometry('400x250')

        button = Button(self, text="Открыть дочернее окно", command=self.open_child_window)
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def open_child_window(self):
        child_window = ChildWindow()


def main():
    apllication = MainWindow()
    apllication.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтоб в главном окне нужно было вводить логин и парль, если они правельны, то это окто закрывается и открывается другое....
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: больше не актуально, решил сам. Спасибо за помощь